# Why is init() method required when I can initialise variables in paint() when writing a Applet

Tags: java, applet

I am new to programming and to Applets as well. 
Its mentioned in my book that init() method should be used to initialise variables and that paint is called each time output needs to be redrawn on the screen.

But the following code works just fine. Why is init() needed then?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

/*
<applet code = "demo" width = 500 height = 600>
</applet>
*/

public class demo extends Applet{
    String msg;
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        int x = 45;

        msg = "Inside paint-----" + x;
        g.drawString(msg, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works if you want `x` and `msg` to be those same values every time. What if you want them to start with one value, but then change that value later?

Comment: Because the paint() method is for paintng and the init() method is for initializing.

Answer (score 0):

`paint` is called every time the screen needs to be redrawn.

`init` is only called once when there is some initialization to be done.

So, it is possible to do the work in `paint`, but it gets called repeatedly and so the cost can be expensive in some cases.

The key thing then is to determine if the expense of any initialization work that needs to be done once for the applet is too much for each call to `paint`, and design your use of the methods based on this.

After a quick web search, [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htm) seems like a good overview.